# Is there a programmatic way to determine if IIS Logging has stopped?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003

I could not find a tool to tell me if IIS logging has stopped, so I thought I could write something.  I don't know where to begin though.  I am using Windows 2003 server and my IIS logging keeps dying.  I can get the error message, but I want to know when it is going down and be alerted by an email.

Not sure what to do.  Maybe some hook into the event viewer?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:  I found eventtriggers.exe from MS here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901

I believe I can use that with a vbscript.  I'll keep searching.

Comment: Maybe check out IIS programmatic administration? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524877(v=vs.90).aspx